# Resize UITableView font when textLabel length is over 20 chars?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to resize the font of my UITableView cells.
If they contain too long titles, the textLabel is split.

So, how can i resize the font when the label length goes over 20 character, in example?
I thought:

```
NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
if (cellText.length > 20){
    cellText = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
}
```

But there's something wrong 'cause it crashes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellText` is an `NSString` and you are setting a `UIFont` to `NSString` pointer, you should set Font to `textLabel`, like this:

```
NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
if (cellText.length > 20){
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
}
```

if not the problem then, please post the crash log also.

Comment: Seems like I found a way to do it, similar to what you did. 
But now it shows labels which have length below "20" char in Font size:11.

Comment: then put an else condition also and set the default font for that. :)

Comment: How to return the max characters of the textLabel like max 10  ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need code for this !

in the inspector :

- Set font size
- set a min font size
- And then check the "ajust to fit"

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;    

UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 300, 20)];
cellLabel.text =cellText;
cellLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[cellLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cellLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f]];
cellLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;       
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
[cellLabel release];
```